# Flutter - get_it error : Invalid argument (Object of type AppModel is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter

I use Flutter and the package get_it in version 4.

In my `main.dart` I have :

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _registerAppLevelObjects();
  _resetInProgressFlag();

  await DotEnv().load('.env');

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> _registerAppLevelObjects() async {
  di.registerSingleton(AppDatabase.getInstance());
  di.registerSingleton(DeviceInfoPlugin());
  di.registerSingleton(DeviceInfoRepository(di.get()));
  di.registerSingleton(Api(di.get()));
  di.registerSingleton(DossierRepository(di.get(), di.get()));
  di.registerSingleton(CenterRepository(di.get()));
  di.registerSingleton(SharedPreferences.getInstance());
}

Future<void> _resetInProgressFlag() async {
  final repo = di.get<DossierRepository>();
  repo.resetInProgressFlag();
}
```

And I have this error :

> No type Api is registered inside GetIt.

Only `DossierRepository` relies on Api. I think the order of calls is good.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use await before your async methods.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await _registerAppLevelObjects();
  await _resetInProgressFlag();

  await DotEnv().load('.env');

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```